# TypeError: bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, server, network-programming

The purpose of the code below is, to check if the server is running and the HTML file code is accessible, if not then send the error " 404 Not Found ". For example: if the user writes

> localhost:6789/hello.html

the output will be = hello but if he writes

> localhost:6789/hello1.html

then the output will be " 404 not found " in the browser.

but the code below works for the first output but for the second output, it gives me the following error.

```
 connectionSocket.send("\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The Complete implemented code is given below.

```
# import socket module
from socket import *
import sys
#import socket
# In order to terminate the program

# Create a TCP server socket
# (AF_INET is used for IPv4 protocols)
# (SOCK_STREAM is used for TCP)
serverPort = 6789
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

'''***Prepare a server socket***'''

# Fill in start

serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print(f"The web server is up on the port {serverSocket}")
# Fill in end

while True:
    # Establish the connection
    print("Ready to serve...")
    # Fill in start
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    # Fill in end

    try:
        # Fill in start
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print(message, "\n" '::', message.split()[0], "\n" ':', message.split()[1])
        filename = message.split()[1]
        print(filename, "||", filename[1:])
        # Fill in end
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputData = f.read()
        # print(outputData)
        # Send one HTTP header line into socket
        # Fill in start
        connectionSocket.send("\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
       # connectionSocket.send(outputData)
        # Fill in end

        # Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputData)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputData[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()


    except IOError:
        # Send response message for file not found
        # Fill in start
        connectionSocket.send("\nHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \n\r\n")
        # Fill in end
        # Close client socket
        # Fill in start
        connectionSocket.send("<html> <head> </head><body><h1> 404 Not Found </h1> </body></html>\r\n")
        connectionSocket.close()
    # Fill in end

serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()  # Terminate the program after sending the corresponding data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your string to bytes with `b` like below

```
connectionSocket.send(b"\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
```